# Dataflows credential issue when connecting to a database table in Azure SQL Server

Tags: powerbi, azure-sql-database

I have a database table created in Azure SQL Server. From SSMS, I use "Azure Active Directory - Universal with MFA" authentication to connect.

[image: Universal with MFA]

I've been informed that the server is configured with disabled public network access, so we

1. Had the Power BI gateway vm "whitelisted" on the Azure SQL server
2. In the dataflow, we use the gateway to connect.
3. Created a database user account for the dataflow connection.

However, we still get "invalid" credential error. Do I miss anything? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Did you set the user as active directory admin in SQL server ?

Comment: @Bhavani The database user account is "test". You mean setting "test" user as active directory admin in Azure Portal? No, we didn't.

Comment: Are you having issue with PowerBI or SSMS ? Could you please add some more information?

Comment: @Bhavani No, I don't have issue in Power BI desktop or SSMS. The connection credential issue only occurs in creating a dataflow.

Comment: Did you check credentials which you are provided are correct?

Answer (score 0):

I created User “test” in my database db from created login using below code:

CREATE USER [test] FOR LOGIN [testLogin];

I tried to create dataflow with Azure SQL server I got the same error:

[image]

Even though I have given correct credentials I am getting above error. In my case issue is with my database name when connecting to database I have given"[db]" as database name instead of “db” I resolved the issue by giving proper name of the database.

[image]

It connected successfully without any error:

[image]